# Subtable does not act normal

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I would like to render two tables side by side. Thus, I started to use the `subtable` environment. The below is the MWE and the problem is that the tables are not side by side and the captions are not aligned as shown at the enclosed figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Results of Entropy}
    \begin{footnotesize}
      \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \caption{(N\tnote{a}=17)}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \toprule
 \hline
   & a & b  \\
 \hline\hline
         \midrule
 Entropy \tnote{b} & 2.1 & 3.34\\
 \hline
  \bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
      \centering
       \caption{ (N\tnote{a}=1696)}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \toprule

 \hline
   & a & b  \\
   \hline\hline
            \midrule

 Entropy \tnote{b} & 6.76 & 8.9 \\
 \hline
 \bottomrule

 \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}


      \begin{tablenotes}\tiny
        \item[a] Number of queries.
        \item[b] Total acquired entropy
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}

\end{footnotesize}

\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just as if you used two `x` if you put a blank line between them they are in separate paragraphs so stack vertically, if you put a linebreak between them then you get a word space (so no room for two subtable that are .5\textwidth, you need no space at all between them to fit two on a line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Alright, but the captions arent aligned yet and I want a little bit of space between two tables. They are too close.

Comment: if you want space between them, add some space , eg `\hfill` and make them less than .5\textwidth wide, if they are both that wide there is no space for space between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threeparttable` tries hard to catch `tabular` environments inside it and also `\caption` commands.

You can do without it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\caption{Results of Entropy}

\subcaptionbox{(N\tnote{a}=17)}[.45\textwidth]{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
  \toprule
    & a & b  \\
  \midrule
  Entropy\tnote{b} & 2.1 & 3.34\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}
\subcaptionbox{(N\tnote{a}=1696)}[.45\textwidth]{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
  \toprule
    & a & b  \\
  \midrule
  Entropy\tnote{b} & 6.76 & 8.9 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[a] Number of queries.
  \item[b] Total acquired entropy
\end{tablenotes}

\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: does this mean that you can never use ´´subtable with ´´threeparttable?

Comment: @stars83clouds A `threepartsubtable` environment would be needed, I guess.